# Automator slows down to a crawl following a simple AppleScript workflow?

Tags: applescript, automator, automation

**Context:** I am trying to use Automator to turn the pages of a web-based e-reader open in Google Chrome, copy their respective HTML code from Chrome Developer Tools (which is already kept open), save it to a file already open in Visual Studio Code, and repeat the steps a specific number of times.

This is the **AppleScript code** I wrote to do that (**EDIT:** and the Automator workflow runs just this script, nothing else):

```
on run {input, parameters}

    tell application "Google Chrome" to activate

    tell application "System Events"
        repeat 3 times
            key code 124 -- right arrow
            delay 0.5
        end repeat
        delay 1

        key code 50 using command down -- cmd + `
        delay 6
    end tell

    repeat 6 times
        tell application "System Events"
            repeat 2 times
                key code 124 -- right arrow
                delay 0.5
                key code 125 -- down arrow
                delay 0.5
            end repeat
            key code 125 -- down
            delay 0.5
            repeat 2 times
                key code 124 -- right
                delay 0.5
                key code 125 -- down
                delay 0.5
            end repeat
            delay 0.5
            keystroke "c" using command down -- cmd + c
            delay 1
            repeat 5 times
                key code 125 -- down
                delay 0.5
            end repeat
        end tell

        tell application "Visual Studio Code" to activate
        delay 1

        tell application "System Events"
            keystroke "v" using command down -- cmd + v
            delay 1
            repeat 2 times
                key code 36 -- return
                delay 0.5
            end repeat
            keystroke "s" using command down -- cmd + s
            delay 1
        end tell

        tell application "Google Chrome" to activate
        delay 1
    end repeat

    tell application "System Events"
        key code 50 using command down -- cmd + `
        delay 1
    end tell

    return input
end run
```

**Problem:** The workflow is very simple, and as far as I can tell, so is the code I wrote. But for some reason, when I run the code in Automator, it slows down to a crawl. Monitoring the process closely, I can tell that it's slowing down while attempting the steps under `repeat 6 times` (in the code) for the 2nd or 3rd time.

What am I doing wrong here?

*Please note that the code runs flawlessly the first time.*

**I've tried:**

- Removing `return input`, which I felt wasn't necessary.
- Removing all `repeat` blocks and coding all the steps manually.
- Restarting my computer and applications.

That didn't work.

---

### Update

Without the first and the last 2 lines from the code block above, I am able to run the AppleScript in *Keyboard Maestro* (demo) without any issues whatsoever.

Now I am not sure if my code is bad or Automator is.

**Update #2:** Did the same as above with the *Script Editor* (pre-installed) app, and it went smooth as well. (Also meaning installing Keyboard Maestro wasn't necessary at all.)

Comment: — Well, tested as best I can (I used TextEdit instead of Visual Studio, and used a random webpage). I didn't see any slowdown in performance. Try my diagnostic method: Type in the lines `say "A"`, `say "B"`, etc: I put one in before each of the inner repeat loops, and before the `keystroke "c"... ` line. this will call out the letter as the script progresses, and by listening and moving the `say` lines around you can narrow in on the exact point it hangs.

Comment: @TedWrigley I monitored this very closely and too many times. It doesn't hang at the same point. Sometimes it starts slowing down in the 2nd loop, sometimes in the 3rd loop, sometimes in the 2nd step, sometimes in the 3rd step (of the loop), etc. It varies each time. Which is why I thought it was a memory leak or something which could (probably) be caused by bad code or an Automator bug.

Comment: Could you link to an actual webpage you might use this script on? It's hard to do a proper test without valid data.